# How can I generate a nether fortress part?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was looking into structure blocks.
I noticed that in the structures folder there is no files about the nether fortress, or I'm blind.

How do I load in a nether fortress part?
Or might it be possible with the new `/placefeature` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `/placefeature` does not allow you to place anything besides decorative features, such as trees, geodes, and desert wells. Full structures (or parts of structures) such as woodland mansions, villagers, and igloos can be summoned with structure blocks [as detailed in the Structure Blocks wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block#Load), but unfortunately this does not currently include structures such as the End Stronghold or Nether Fortresses.

In short, I do not believe it is currently possible to manually generate a portion of a Nether Fortress without the assistance of external tools.

Comment: Ah bummer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t find a nether fortress, you can always turn on cheats and use the /locate nether fortress command. You will need to be in the nether while doing this so that you will get the coordinates of the fortress.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I was looking how to generate one myself.